# Multiplicator caption position in tikz plot

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create a plot with two separate y-axes. The right y-axis is units * 10^5. However, the multiplication caption is not positioned correctly. I use the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis y line* = left,
    xlabel = grid size $l$,
    ylabel = \textcolor{blue}{\footnotesize$\blacksquare$}
indices per $\mathcal{T}$,
    ymode = log,
    log origin=infty]
    \addplot[color=blue,mark=x] coordinates {
          (15000,317.631)
          (20000,182.318)
          (40000,49.3089)
          (80000,14.4933)
          (160000,5.02436)
          (320000,2.37795)
          (500000,1.81145)
          (640000,1.62701)
          (1280000,1.29392)
          (2560000,1.18447)
      };
  \end{axis}

  \begin{axis}[
        hide x axis,
        ylabel near ticks,
        axis y line*=right,
        ylabel={\textcolor{red}{\footnotesize$\blacksquare$}  number of $\mathcal{T}_{pot}$}]
            \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
          (15000,40819)
          (20000,41179)
          (40000,41179)
          (80000,42720)
          (160000,44312)
          (320000,44866)
          (640000,98610)
          (1280000,168980)
          (2560000,184202)
      };
      \draw[black,dashed] (axis cs:500000,0) -- (axis cs:500000,200000);
      \draw (axis cs:500000,200000) node[below right] {$l_r$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which produces this result:

[image]

However, I want the *10^5 in the upper right corner to be aligned right of the y-axis, not left of it. It should be aligned just like the tick labels for the right y-axis.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The option you need to adjust is `y tick scale label style`.  If you specify this to be

```
at={(yticklabel cs:1.05)}
```

this will be placed in line with the other ticks on the y-axis, 5% beyond the end.  If you specify

```
at={(yticklabel cs:1.05,10pt)}
```

then it will be moved `10pt` further to the right.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots,amssymb}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis y line* = left,
    xlabel = grid size $l$,
    ylabel = \textcolor{blue}{\footnotesize$\blacksquare$}
indices per $\mathcal{T}$,
    ymode = log,
    log origin=infty]
    \addplot[color=blue,mark=x] coordinates {
          (15000,317.631)
          (20000,182.318)
          (40000,49.3089)
          (80000,14.4933)
          (160000,5.02436)
          (320000,2.37795)
          (500000,1.81145)
          (640000,1.62701)
          (1280000,1.29392)
          (2560000,1.18447)
      };
  \end{axis}

  \begin{axis}[
        hide x axis,
        ylabel near ticks,
        axis y line*=right,
        y tick scale label style={at={(yticklabel cs:1.05,10pt)}},
        ylabel={\textcolor{red}{\footnotesize$\blacksquare$}  number of $\mathcal{T}_{pot}$}]
            \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
          (15000,40819)
          (20000,41179)
          (40000,41179)
          (80000,42720)
          (160000,44312)
          (320000,44866)
          (640000,98610)
          (1280000,168980)
          (2560000,184202)
      };
      \draw[black,dashed] (axis cs:500000,0) -- (axis cs:500000,200000);
      \draw (axis cs:500000,200000) node[below right] {$l_r$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```